# How to compare variable $p in a list with variables that came before it?

Tags: php, html, list, variables

Alright, so this may seem like a strange question but I've got this list of variables, $r1-$r50, and I would like to compare all these variables to each other. However, I only want to look backwards in the list, so if I take a look at $r23 I do not want to compare it to $r24 and above. Is there a way to do this easily? I'm currently trying to use variable variables but I can't get them working. I have looked around but all I've found has to do with easily comparing one variable to many others, not to comparing to previous ones. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
<?php
$r0 = "&nbsp;";
$nr = 1;
$vnr = 1;
$concheck = "true"; // I use this to break out of my while loop, I guess I could use break; maybe but meh.

while ($nr < 50) {

$nrtemp = 0;

while ($concheck == "true") {

if ($r{$nr} == $r{$nrtemp}) {

echo "($r{$nr} == $r{$nrtemp})";
//remove variable;
$concheck = "false";

} elseif ($nrtemp >= 50) {

echo "($nrtemp >= 50)";
$v{$vnr} = $r{$nr};
++$vnr;
$concheck = "false";

} else {

echo "else";
++$nrtemp;
$concheck = "true";

};

};

++$nr;

};
?>
```

To further clarify:

All I basically want to do to is filter the list. For example:

```
$r1 = "a";
$r2 = "b";
$r3 = "c";
$r4 = "b";
$r5 = "e";
$r6 = "f";
```

But I don't want 2 variables specifying "b".
I want to end up with a list of variables without any doubles. And that's basically it.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easy is to maintain an array. Put all values to that array and apply `array_unique()` and you will get a list of unique/non-repeated value.

Ref: [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Alright, I tried it and it should work, but it gives the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /home/u612610050/public_html/scholeia/lbron/bronnen_my.html on line 421